# How can I connect an OLED display to arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I'm new on this!

So I want to know if is it posible to connect this oled display: [oled display](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/1-51-inch-Transparent-OLED-Screen_62356046434.html?spm=a2756.order-detail-ta-ta-b.0.0.49882fc2kEiqxv) to [arduino nano](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano) and if is it posible where can I found information of how to learn about connect this type of mini display.

And if you can share some links about good learning site would be cool too!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll have trouble connecting it, as it does not seem to come with an interface card, just with a bare small pitch connector that will be very hard to solder. It looks like there's no technical documentation, which for me would be a deal breaker. If you're a beginner I would advise against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you have the adaptor board for it as shown in the video.

The key item from the description to note is the driver chip: **SSD1309**

That is what you need to know to find a library and connection schema.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

And is it posible to buy a generic adaptor or made one? 

Because I ask to seller and the adaptor is to expensive more than 10 times the price of the screen...

Thanks in advance

PD: I find this new [oled display](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15173) that I think it would be better.

Comment: No, there's no such thing as a "generic" adaptor. Every display is different. The datasheet for the display should have a schematic for what the interfacing needs are. If there is no datasheet then don't buy it.

Comment: Don't do it. It is an expensive display as it is, and it's not made to be easily used with an Arduino, especially without an interface card and 5V / 3.3V conversion. If you want an OLED attached to an Arduino Nano there are displays that are much easier to interface and use.

Comment: @StarCat Ah, but it's "transparent".  Gotta charge 10x as much if you remove that back plate...

Comment: So this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15173 would be better I imagine?

And of the first one I have the datasheet.